# Other resolved origin is not allowed for the given client ID when implement Google Sign In

Tags: google-sso

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       docker.host
```

This is my hosts file setup recently. I have added the docker.host to the Authorised JavaScript origins but I have received the following error message when using this domain "**The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.**". But I have no problem using localhost. Is the Authorised origins does not works on resolved domain other than localhost?